# Using F# Fake SquirrelHelper to create Squirrel.Windows packages

Tags: f#-fake, squirrel.windows

Attempting to create a SquirrelPack target however it does not seem to be working for me using the docs:

`// line 84
    Target "CreateSquirrelPackage" (fun _ ->
        SquirrelPack (fun p -> {p with WorkingDir = "./tmp"}) "./my.nuget"
    )
    // line 88`

Output

`build.fsx(86,49): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
        string option
    but here has type
        string`

Has anyone been able to get SquirrelPack working in F#Fake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorkingDir` [has type `string option`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/SquirrelHelper.fs#L66), but you're trying to make it just a `string`.

This should work:

```
Target "CreateSquirrelPackage" (fun _ ->
    SquirrelPack (fun p -> {p with WorkingDir = Some "./tmp"}) "./my.nuget"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I obviously need to study the F# language further to better understand these concepts.Thanks again

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it?